# Why nativewind not work in different directory still after you define that directory in tailwind.config.js?

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

Nativewind not work in different directory still after you define that directory in tailwind.config.js

This is my tailwind.config.js
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eLqL.png)

This is my folder structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEaBj.png)

Comment: Please check this guide on  [How to ask Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [why should you not upload image of code or Error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)